# Unity3D - Are PlayerPrefs the same for every device that downloads my apk?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android

Just a quick question,

I'm about to upload my first game to the PlayStore when I thought of something.
I've made a script that makes the newScore the new highScore when newScore > highScore. I've used PlayerPrefs to do this. After testing my game a couple of times the highScore is now 51 for **me**. Will people that download my game start with the same highScore of 51, or will they start at 0 (like I want them to)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google Play has a means for managing things like high score. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a pretty pointless thing to do for PlayerPrefs. And also easier to achieve by simply initializing the score counter to a given value.

So no, other players will not start with your PlayerPrefs values. It's not specifically [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) but the user-specific folders starting with `~/...` are a clear indicator.

Answer (score 1):

PlayerPrefs file is stored locally on the users phone, and will only contain the data that that user generates, so it will only show the high score that was achieved on their phone

Comment: I'm only able to accept one answer, but thank you very much,.